# .Net Core web API Docker (Linux) - unable to load libMyCpp.so file

Tags: docker, shared-libraries, asp.net-core-webapi, docker-container, .so

I have a .NetCore web API and and need to connect with a C++ shared library (libCppAppOutput.so). For this I am using DllImport inside the controller of the Web API as in the below code:

```
[DllImport("libCppAppOutput.so", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, EntryPoint = "methodNameinCppProject")] 
public static extern int MethodNameInWebAPI(string param1, string param2);
```

When I am debugging it in Visual studio with Windows environment, I am getting an exception like

> An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.
> (0x8007000B).

This may be because of trying to access a Linux file in Windows environment, if I am using a **CppAppOutput.dll** in place of **libCppAppOutput.so** I can successfully call the methods inside the dll. **But my actual requirement is to run the entire application in Linux environment and to be proceed with .so file only**, so I have created a docker image with target OS as Linux and tried to call the methods inside it from running docker with the below command :

```
docker run -p 8081:80 name_of_docker_image:tagname
```

Then I am getting an exception like:

> Unable to load shared library 'libCppAppOutput.so' or one of its dependencies. In order to help diagnose loading problems, consider
> setting the LD_DEBUG environment variable: libCppAppOutput.so: cannot
> open shared object file: No such file or directory.

But I can see the file, **libCppAppOutput.so** is present inside the docker image by using the following commands,

```
docker create --name name_of_container name_of_docker_image:tagname
docker start name_of_container 
docker exec -ti name_of_container /bin/bash
root@xyzabc:/app# ls
```

I am using below URL to test the application

http://localhost:8081/launchUrl/MethodNameInWebAPI/param1/param2

Please help me in this regard like how can I call a .so file from the Linux docker.
if this issue to be elaborated more, kindly comment and I will do.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could able to solve this issue with help from my colleagues and friends.
There was a dependency with libCppAppOutput.so (an XML parser). Even though that dependency package is installed in the container, it was missed to configure while creating the libCppAppOutput.so.
This was identified by executing *ldl libCppAppOutput.so* command in **bash**.

Thank you all for spend time on reading and analyzing the question !
Have more N more great coding days!

Comment: Did you mean "ldd"? Because "ldl" is not found as a command